# Concisely write vector expression in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two vectors: `v1 = [1,2,3,4], v2 = [4,5,6,7]`. I then wish to compute the expression(for some reason stackoverflow does not support latex, so I will take a picture
[image]

I am by no means a master of NumPy, so I would write this in python as

```
sum = 0
for i in range(K):
    exp1 = np.sqrt(v1[i]*v2[i])
    sum += exp1
```

I am almost 100% sure that this can be done much more concisely. How would you write this mathematical expression?

Comment: `v1` and `v2` are *lists* Are you working with `numpy.ndarray` objects in actuality?

Comment: yes sir, i define them as ndarrays

Answer (score 1):

```
In [308]: v1,v2 = np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([4,5,6,7])
```

The element wise product:  (assuming K means all elements)

```
In [309]: v1*v2
Out[309]: array([ 4, 10, 18, 28])
In [310]: np.sqrt(v1*v2)
Out[310]: array([2.        , 3.16227766, 4.24264069, 5.29150262])
```

Sum the sqrts:

```
In [311]: np.sum(np.sqrt(v1*v2))
Out[311]: 14.696420969416847
```

Your code:

```
In [313]: sum = 0
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     exp1 = np.sqrt(v1[i]*v2[i])
     ...:     sum += exp1
     ...: 
In [314]: sum
Out[314]: 14.696420969416847
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `sum` for variable. Second, try:

```
out = np.sqrt(np.sqrt(np.dot(v1,v2))).sum()
# out:
# 2.783157683713741
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the following:

```
((v1[:K]*v2[:K])**(1/2)).sum()
```

Or alternatively:

```
(np.sqrt(v1[:K]*v2[:K])).sum()
```